# Component selection - difference between 4027 and 4027N flip flops

Tags: components, flipflop

I am building a [simple circuit](http://www.instructables.com/id/Use-a-Momentary-or-Tactile-Switch-as-a-Pushbutton-/step3/Using-the-J-K-flip-flop/) that will use a J-K flip flop to enable me to use a momentary switch as a toggle.

[image]

The circuit diagram states that a 4027N should be used.

My local supplier has a [4027 in stock](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/4027-cmos-logic-hcfhef-qx16s).

This is a really basic question I'm sure, but is this the same thing? What does that trailing *N* in the name mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alternative will be fine.

The trailing letters tend to be manufacturer specific, usually identifying the package (e.g. SOIC, DIP, etc.) or other properties like being lead free, or industrial/automotive/military temperature ranges, etc.

An example is the NXP version of the 4027. They have two:

- HEF4027BP
- HEF4027BT

For them, the 'P' one is the DIP package and the 'T' one is the SOIC package. But according to one of their other [datasheets](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/hef4072b.pdf) (granted for a different part), they use **'N'** to signify a DIP package in America. This is probably where the 'N' comes from in that schematic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't think there's any issue here with switch bounce? If the switch does bounce, the clock input may see multiple 0->1 rising edge transitions for a single press of the switch, toggling the output multiple times.

Comment: Recommendations for a switch debouncing circuit welcome, Dean.

Comment: From what I remember Schmitt trigger circuit is often used - or a logic gate which has a schmitt input. And a capacitor is included to remove any spikes caused by the switch.

Implementations can also be done with SR latches.

Here's a couple of links for you.          

http://www.all-electric.com/schematic/debounce.htm

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember Schmitt trigger circuit is often used - or a logic gate which has a schmitt input. And a capacitor is included to remove any spikes caused by the switch.

Implementations can also be done with SR latches.

Here's a couple of links for you.

http://www.all-electric.com/schematic/debounce.htm

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eng.utah.edu%2F~cs5780%2Fdebouncing.pdf&ei=FOFYVe2cK4TXU5iMgLAN&usg=AFQjCNEppSfSIc313thRdgXgoWieieFjFw